# Lazy Loading Image concept definition and Implementation

Tags: android, lazy-loading, universal-image-loader

OK so there are 2 concepts for **Lazy Loading** from all I have read.

1. Load images in a background thread.
2. Only display the image when the user is not interacting with the screen. (i.e. display it when the user have stopped scrolling)

My question would be, which one of those would be the right one.

For implementation, I'm using **Universal Image Loader**. Is it possible to implement **concept #2** with this library natively, or should I add some extra code?

Answer (score -1):

First off, you should know there isn't "right" or "wrong" one when it comes to user experience. It all depends on your way of thinking. However, based on Android guidelines, you should never perform heavy tasks on the main tread as it might affect user experience. It means you should always try to load images on a background thread.

But the question is whether you should keep loading and unloading the images as the user scrolls or you should only display the image once the user stops scrolling. I "personally" believe that the answer depends on the situation. For example imagine a your facebook friends list where there is names tags beside the images. In this case, you might not need to load all pictures as the user is able to search the list, scroll up and down and pick the right friend based on the name. However, if the user is expected to pick and select merely on the image. Then for sure the answer is to display the image once it is available.

Comment: This is not what I asked ._.